# Javascript detect which host it was loaded from

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-domain, detection, hostname

I have a Javascript library I'm working on.  It can be self-hosted or run from another server.  The script makes a number of AJAX calls and the preferred method is making POST requests to the same host as the including page.  To allow for cross-domain calls it also supports JSONP, but this limits the amount of data that can be sent (~2K to safely accommodate most modern browsers' URL length limits).

Obviously the user including the script knows where they're getting it from and could manually select JSONP as needed, but in the interest of simplifying things, I'd like to detect, within the script itself, whether the script was loaded from the same host as the page including it or not.

I'm able to grab the script element with jQuery but doing a $('script').attr('src') is only returning a relative path (e.g. "/js/my-script.js" not "http://hostname.com/js/my-script.js") even when it's being loaded from a different host.

Is this possible and if so, how would I go about it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It doesn't make any difference where a JavaScript source file was loaded from.  Whether or not an AJAX call crosses domains depends only on where the main HTML file came from.

Comment: And that is what I am trying to ascertain: whether the script was loaded from the same host as the page (and will thus need to make its calls to the same host as the page) or whether it was loaded from another host relative to the page (and will thus need to make JSONP calls x-domain).  What, specifically I intend to do doesn't matter, the fundamental question remains: can a script determine the host it was loaded from to compare to document.location.hostname.

Comment: You misunderstand. The **only** domain that matters is the domain of the main page. That's why you can load jQuery from the Google CDN and it works **exactly** the same as if you had loaded it from your own domain. You're trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist :)

Comment: Maybe I have been unclear in how this all fits together (though you are ignoring the actual question, I will point out).  Whatever host the script is loaded from is the host to which it will make its calls.  If that host is the same as the page loading the script I will $.post so I can make calls with large amounts of data at once. If the loading host is different I will need to $.ajax with dataType: 'jsonp' to get around the x-domain restriction and will thus need to send data in smaller chunks (< ~2K / call).

Comment: Well yes, I'm ignoring the question; that's why I'm typing comments and not answers :) In general you can't rely on your code being able to tell where it comes from. What I'm trying to point out is that, rare and weird circumstances excepted, you don't have to.

Comment: Please see my updated comment.  Pressing enter annoyingly posted prematurely.

Comment: Oh *now* I see what you're asking; your script talks to some server, and its design is such that it talks to the server it came from implicitly. OK, well that counts as a rare and weird circumstance I guess :)  My apologies.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39569/discussion-between-theraccoonbear-and-pointy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use JSONP, use CORS headers.

But if you really want to do JS check, use `var t = $('script')[0].outerHTML`.

Effect on my page:
`[20:43:34.865] "<script src="http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js" async="" type="text/javascript"></script>"`

Comment: CORS is great if you're not required to support browsers with substantial market penetration.

Comment: Doesn't matter. `element.outerHTML` is answer even for IE 4.0.

Answer (score -3):

Checking `location.host` should do the trick.

Comment: That addresses the location of the page, not the script.  The comments and subsequent chat above clarify all of this.